# Nested V-For active Class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm trying to bind an active class @click to a nested item in array of objects.

i have the following array:

```js
var arr =
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Main Name 1"
    "parents": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Name1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Main Name 2"
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Name3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In Vue.js I Loop through this array like this:

```js
<v-col cols="2" v-for="main in arr" :key="main.id">
  <b>Table {{main.name}}</b>
  <v-card
  class="ma-2 pb-6"
  v-for="parent in main.parents" :key="parent.id"
  @click="doSomeStuff"
  >
    <v-card-title>{{parent.name}}</v-card-title>
  </v-card>
</v-col>
```

I want to set an active class on the clicked element on the nested v-for.
I've tried it like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/256701/).

But this gives every first element in the array that class.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the id of the last clicked element and bind a class depending on that id.

Also the format of the `arr` was wrong.

[Conditional class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeId: -1,
    arr: [{
        id: 10,
        name: "Main Name 1",
        parents: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "Name1"
        }]
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "Main Name 2",
        parents: [{
            id: 2,
            name: "Name2"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Name3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    setActive(id) {
       this.activeId = id;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div cols="2" v-for="main in arr" :key="main.id">
    <h2>Table {{main.name}}</h2>
    <div class="ma-2 pb-6" v-for="parent in main.parents" :key="parent.id" @click="setActive(parent.id)" :class="{ 'active' : activeId === parent.id}">
      <h3>{{parent.name}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```